# Error al introducir una imagen/archivo a la base de datos mediante php

Tags: php, mysql

Que tal estoy estudiando programación y estoy haciendo un formulario que suba datos e imágenes. El formulario funciona, pero al momento de visualizar lo que envié a la BBDD solo veo [BLOB - 0 B], es decir, no cargó la imagen. Leí por ahí que es mejor subir la imagen a un directorio de mi proyecto y subir la dirección de ese archivo a la BBDD para ocupar menos espacio y sea más eficiente. El problema? No sé cómo encaminarlo. Este es el código de la dirección:

```php
<?php
$nombre_imagen=$_FILES["imagen"]["name"];
$tipo_imagen=$_FILES["imagen"]["type"];
$tamano_imagen=$_FILES["imagen"]["size"];

$destination_folder=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/assets/images/';

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"],$nombre_imagen.$destination_folder);
?>
```

Acá declaro la variable dándole el valor de la BBDD

```
<?php
   include ("database_inventario.php");
   $inventario= new Database();

   if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
   $descripcion = $inventario->sanitize($_POST['descripcion']);
   $marca = $inventario->sanitize($_POST['marca']);
   $cantidad = $inventario->sanitize($_POST['cantidad']);
   $tamano = $inventario->sanitize($_POST['tamano']);
   $talle = $inventario->sanitize($_POST['talle']);
   $precio = $inventario->sanitize($_POST['precio']);
   $imagen = $inventario->sanitize($_POST['imagen']);
   $nameImg = $inventario->sanitize($_POST['nameImg']);
   $typefile = $inventario->sanitize($_POST['typefile']);


   $res = $inventario->create($descripcion, $marca, $cantidad, $tamano, $talle, $precio, $imagen, $nameImg, $typefile);
   if($res){
   $message= "Producto cargado con éxito.";
   $class="alert alert-success col-12";
   }else{
   $message="No fue posible cargar el producto.";
   $class="alert alert-danger col-12";
}
?>
```

Y acá mi BBDD

[image: BBDD]

Al final del código puse var_dump($_POST) y var_dump($_FILES); y me genera lo siguiente:

```
array (size=7)
  'tamano' => string '' (length=0)
  'cantidad' => string '' (length=0)
  'precio' => string '' (length=0)
  'descripcion' => string '' (length=0)
  'talle' => string '' (length=0)
  'marca' => string '' (length=0)
  'btnCargar' => string 'Cargar' (length=6)

array (size=1)
  'imagen' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'asfaf.jpg' (length=9)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php30D0.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 46151
```

Agradezco toda ayuda y recomendación, desde ya gracias!

Comment: revisa que el move_uploaded_file te ha guardado el fichero en el destino que pones. si es asi, entonces solo te faltaria, cuando hagas el guardado en la BBDD, añadir en el campo imageImg (por ej) la ruta que has puesto en el move_uploaded_file. En tu caso, `$nombre_imagen.$destination_folder`

Comment: Agrega temporalmente estas tres líneas al inicio de tu script y dinos qué errores ves en pantalla, así podremos ayudarte mejor: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);` También, considera poner en la pregunta todo lo que sea código como texto, no como imagen, pues es más fácil analizar el texto que un código en una captura de pantalla, además es más simple para ti, pues sólo tendrías que copiar/pegar el código en la pregunta.

Comment: @Jakala Una vez que cargo el archivo en el input file, me carga en la BBDD pero no llega a cargar la imagen, solo hace una falsa subida y no me da error, pero tampoco mueve el archivo que introduje a la carpeta que especcifiqué

Comment: acabo de fijarme que tienes puesto al reves el nombre destino del archivo. tienes puesto `$nombre_imagen.$destination_folder` y deberia ser al reves, primero carpeta y luego archivo. algo como `$destination_folder.$nombre_imagen`. Lo dicho. revisa que errores te va dando. y sigue el consejo de @A.Cedano, que ademas es buena practica.

Comment: @Jakala, inicialmente estaba como decís, lo intercambié para ver si funcionaba de tal manera pero veo que no, según veo los errores que me saltan, parece ser que algo no está leyéndose bien y por ende el "move_uplodad_file" no me mueve los archivos, el problema es que no logro verlo.

Comment: Por favor no uses el área de respuestas para aclarar asuntos relativos a la pregunta. Puedes pulsar en [edit] y agregarlo en la misma pregunta. Además, como ya te dije, pon todo lo que sea código o mensajes de error como texto copiando/pegando, así es mucho más fácil de revisar. Como depuración adicional pon estas dos cosas y nos dices qué muestra: `var_dump($_POST);` y `var_dump($_FILES);` Y, si usas un formulario para pasar los datos al servidor convendría que lo muestres también en la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Disculpa, soy nuevo en el foro, gracias por los aportes. Te hago una consulta, para no tener que pegar todo el contenido y que sea extensa la pregunta, es posible adjuntar un link de git con el código para que puedan ver y entender mejor?

Comment: No hace falta, el propósito de Stackoverflow no es analizar proyectos completos, sino responder a problemas concretos por lo que se recomienda siempre poner en la pregunta únicamente los fragmentos de código donde ocurre el problema. Según los `var_dump` que muestras algunos de los `Undefined index` no deberían estar ocurriendo, otros sí, por ejemplo, no existe una clave `typefiles` en el POST. ¿Podrías decirnos cómo tienes organizado el código (indicando, en los fragmentos de código a qué archivo pertenece cada uno)? Sería bueno también que agregues el HTML del formulario.

Comment: También, copia y pega en la pregunta todos los Warning,Notice, Error o lo que sea que veas en pantalla para analizarlos. Como ya dije, revisarlos en imágenes es más complicado.